# Style link to current :target using only CSS?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to highlight the link the the current :target, using only HMTL and CSS?

```css
:target {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#foo">Foo</a>
  <a href="#bar">Bar</a>
</nav>

<section id="foo">This is foo.</section>

<section id="bar">This is bar.</section>
```

The example highlights the targeted element, but the goal is, to add styling to the link, which has been clicked to get to this target.

Edit: The links will not lead to different HTML pages, only to targets within the current page. This is used as a single-page website, so the URL won't change, but the "#foo" part at the end.

Edit 2: `:local-link` seems to be designed to do exactly what is desired, but it's only a proposal and not supported by any browser. So the question is, if there is a workaround using only supported CSS.

Comment: CSS doesn't know which site you're on. You need JS for it to read out the URL .

Comment: This is true, if we are talking about multiple pages. But CSS knows the ":target" selector, which seems to lead in the right direction for this use case. Still, not sure, if it's possible.

Comment: but with target it know the targeted element not the anchor that was used to target it. As a matter of fact you could have multiple anchors at the same page leading to the same target.

Comment: Sure, and if that is the case, I could use different classes to target these anchors seperately or I could target them all at once. And as shown in my answer below, it is technically possible to select a link leading to a specific target, which will be enough in my use case. So the remaining question is only educational. Is it possible in a generic way for all possible targets?

Comment: No, I don't think so. You could do it without adding classes, `body:has(#foo:target) a[href="#foo"]` - but you will still have to write a selector for each possible link/target, because with CSS you don't actually have "access" to the value `#foo`. You can determine _that_ an element is the target, but not what specific value _made_ it the target.

Comment: Goin further on @CBroe approach then you could sue SASS/LESS to create a list of element ids and iterate through it to create the selectors automatically.

Comment: You can achieve this by applying styles to the :target element itself and then using sibling selectors to style the corresponding link, the CSS rules target the link immediately following the :target element (:target + nav a) and apply specific styles to it based on its href attribute value ([href="#foo"] or [href="#bar"]).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a general way (without explicitly knowing e.g. the ids of the sections) by using the + selector.

It will need every instance to have a selector and I'm not sure I'd recommend it for a handwritten solution for more than a few sections.

```css
:target {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

nav:has(+ :target) a:nth-child(1),
nav:has(+ * + :target) a:nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#foo">Foo</a>
  <a href="#bar">Bar</a>
</nav>

<section id="foo">This is foo.</section>

<section id="bar">This is bar.</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a working solution, but the links have to be known and specified in the CSS:

```css
a {
    color: blue;
}

:target {
    border: 2px solid red;
}

body:has(#foo:target) a[href="#foo"],
body:has(#bar:target) a[href="#bar"] {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#foo">Foo</a>
  <a href="#bar">Bar</a>
</nav>

<section id="foo">This is foo.</section>

<section id="bar">This is bar.</section>
```

Once a user clicks on the `#foo` link, the body has an element with ID `#foo` which also has been targeted, so the selector works and you can access child elements of this body.

Edit: eliminated extra classes as per CBroe's comment above.

Comment: Checking from within the `body` doesn't seem a very optimal way.

Comment: @Chinz changing the order, as your solution is proposing, probably isn't exactly "optimal" either.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why isn't checking from with the `body` a good idea? Does it use too much performance?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working implementation:

```css
:target {
  color: red;
}

#foo:target ~ #target1,
#bar:target ~ #target2 {
  color: magenta;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <section id="foo">This is foo.</section>
   <section id="bar">This is bar.</section>

   <a href="#foo" id="target1">Target 1</a>
   <a href="#bar" id="target2">Target 2</a>
 </body>
```

Comment: You reversed the elements' order

Answer (score 0):

If you were willing to *completely* sacrifice order and structure, you *could* do something like this.

The links *follow* their respective section in the HTML, so that they can be targeted when the section *is* the target, using just `:target + a`.

And the visual order of the elements gets changed by putting it all into a flexbox container, and using the `order` property.

But this would not really be a good idea, I think. Not only would you have to give up on any sort of sensible structure, it would also have tabindex issues - I added a normal link into the content of each section, so when you `[tab]` through the links, you'll see what I mean. You'd have to explicitly add `tabindex` attributes with correct numbering to *all* of your links, to make this work in a sensible manner that the user would expect, again.

```css
div { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }

div > :nth-child(even) {
  color: blue;
  order: -1;
}
:target {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
:target + a {
  color: magenta;
}
```

```html
<div>
<section id="foo">This is <a href="#">foo</a>.</section>
<a href="#foo">Foo</a>

<section id="bar">This is <a href="#">bar</a>.</section>
<a href="#bar">Bar</a>
</div>
```